# Pandas DataFrame: Change column values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df where two column values have `True`, `False` or `NaN`

df

```
            a         b           c

    0      a         True        NaN
    1      b         False       True
    2      c         NaN         False
    3      d         NaN         NaN
    4      e         False       NaN
    5      f         True        False
```

I'm trying to convert the values in columns `b` and `c`.

If `True` comes in one column, another will be `False` If `NaN` present change that `False`.

Similarly for `False`. If `NaN` is present in both columns. Change both values to `False`

Resultant df:

```
            a         b           c

    0      a         True        False
    1      b         False       True
    2      c         True        False
    3      d         False       False
    4      e         False       True
    5      f         True        False
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's try two-step filling:

```
s = df[['b','c']]

# both are `NaN`, fill with `False`
df.loc[s.isna().all(1), ['b','c']] = False

# inverse the sum 
sums = (1 - s.sum(1)).astype(bool)

# fill the remaining `NaN` with the inverse sum
df[['b','c']] = s.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(sums))
```

Output:

```
   a      b      c
0  a   True  False
1  b  False   True
2  c   True  False
3  d  False  False
4  e  False   True
5  f   True  False
```

Comment: Both `NaN` are changing to `True` instead of `False`

Answer (score 1):

There are three inbuilt python methods to change column values based on condition. You can refer to the below link for same:
https://pythonexamples.org/pandas-dataframe-replace-values-in-column-based-on-condition/

My problem statement was for the column ACTIONCODE in data frame (df2) if column value is A/AMEND/correction then change it to MODIFY

```
df2.loc[((df2.ACTIONCODE == 'A') | (df2.ACTIONCODE == 'AMEND') | (df2.ACTIONCODE == 'correction')), 'ACTIONCODE'] = 'MODIFY'
```

NOTE: The or and and python statements require truth-values. For pandas these are considered ambiguous so you should use “bitwise” | (or) or & (and) operations

Answer (score 0):

This uses `numpy where` to check each column for the conditions and replace with the opposite value :

```
cond1 = df.b.notna() & df.c.isna()
cond2 = df.b.isna() & df.c.notna()

df.assign(
    c=lambda x: np.where(cond1, df.b.sub(1).ne(0), df.c),
    b=lambda x: np.where(cond2, df.c.sub(1).ne(0), df.b),
).mask(lambda x: x.isna(), False)


    a   b        c
0   a   True    False
1   b   False   True
2   c   True    False
3   d   False   False
4   e   False   True
5   f   True    False
```

Alternatively, you could use `.loc` and assign the values :

```
cond3 = df.b.isna() & df.c.isna()

df.loc[cond1, "c"] = df.loc[cond1, "b"].sub(1).ne(0)
df.loc[cond2, "b"] = df.loc[cond2, "c"].sub(1).ne(0)
df.loc[cond3, ["b", "c"]] = False
```

Answer (score 0):

create a user-defined function swap:

```
import numpy as np


def swap(x):
  if(x['b']==False and x['c']==np.NaN):
    return True
  if(x['b']==True and x['c']==np.NaN):  
    return False
  else:
    return c  
 def swap2(x):
      if(x['c']==False and x['b']==np.NaN):
        return True
      if(x['c']==True and x['b']==np.NaN):  
        return False
      else:
        return b
```

Then use apply function:

```
df['c']=df.apply(swap, axis=1)

df['b']=df.apply(swap2, axis=1)
```

then fill NAs with false

```
df.fillna(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create filters for conditions

```
na_false = (df['b'].isna()) & (df['c'] == False)

na_true = (df['b'].isna()) & (df['c'] == True)

true_na = (df['b'] == True) & (df['c'].isna())

false_na = (df['b'] == False) & (df['c'].isna())

na_na = (df['b'].isna()) & (df['c'].isna())
```

Set column values using filters

```
df.loc[na_false,'b'] = True

df.loc[na_true,'b'] = False

df.loc[true_na, 'c'] = False

df.loc[false_na, 'c'] = True

df.loc[na_na, ['b', 'c']] = False
```